# Pass validator to child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular14

I'm using an angular child component that implements `ControlValueAccessor` with reactive forms. The child component is essentially just wrapping another component with a few extra things.  So in the parent, when I do this:

```html
<app-child formControlName="foo"></app-child>
```

the form group knows that foo is required. How, in the child component, do I determine that it's required?  I need to add the required attribute in the HTML to the component being wrapped, essentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the child component should be always required, then you can implement the `Validator` interface, and provide the [NG_VALIDATORS](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALIDATORS) token in the child component, to sync the invalid state with the parent form-group.

You can try the following to achieve that in this case:

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  innerCtrl: FormControl; // Use it to access the inner component value and invalid state.
  onValidationChange: () => void;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (this.innerCtrl.invalid) {
      return { invalid: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidationChange = fn;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Otherwise, if the child component shouldn't always be required, then you can inject the `NgControl` from the child component, to check if it has the `required` validator or not, using the [AbstractControl.hasValidator()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasvalidator) API which has been introduced in Angular 12.2.0 (Like how MatInput [shows required asterisk when using required validator](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/4b588d181b18beb74df0560318b129aea1036a63/src/material/input/input.ts#L178))

You can try the following to achieve that in this case:

```js
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  get required(): boolean {
    return this.ngControl?.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required);
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It’s not always required. That’s why I need to know whether the form said it was required or not.

Comment: Well, I updated my answer to include the other case. Please check.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  For anyone else who uses this solution, remember you have to remove the `providers` piece and in the constructor add `this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this`

Comment: tsk. Seems like i am not using Angular 12 as hasValidator() doesnt exist)